# CSS background image is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a CSS background image that will not show, can anyone se why it will not show the image? i cant figure it out myself.

```
    <!-- Section: services -->
<section id="service" class="home-section text-center bg-gray">

    <div class="heading-about">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <div class="section-heading">
                <h2>SCHEMA!</h2>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<br>TEST<br>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /Section: services -->

.service {
width:100%;

position:relative;

background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

Comment: `.service` must be `#service` since service is an ID not a classname

Comment: Is the img a folder?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use #service when referring to ID's of elements.

```
#service {
width:100%;

position:relative;

background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

A good guide on css selectors can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: There are better sources than w3schools of all things (also called "w3fools" for a purpose), but your answer is better than mine because of adding a link. Well done!

Comment: Curious, why the hatred for w3schools? It is simple, but I think it displays things in a nice manner and is good for absolute beginners.

Comment: Oh, that is no hatred! It is just that they are imprecise and outdated sometimes which can lead to great confusion. I would recommend MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors Well written, precise and cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

You define the top level element as:

```
<section id="service" class="home-section text-center bg-gray">
```

So you give it the *id* "service", not the class.

Therefore your css should be:

```
#service {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

Note the leading `#` instead of the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion in your CSS you refer to class ".service{..." instead of a id of section element. So you have to use "#service{..." instead of ".service {..."